# Express doesn't pass object to the view

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Im trying to send a user object from passport to the browser, but all I get is `window.user undefined` in the console.

In the route I've checked the object with `console.log("USER:"+JSON.stringify(req.user, null, 4))`

and I get the proper output:

```
USER :{
    "emails": [
        {}
    ],
    "nick": "nickname",
    "identifier": "76561197990749921",
    "points": 140
}
```

While trying to send it with `res.render('index', {user: req.user});` I cant retrieve it from the window object. But when i send some property for example `res.render('index', {user: req.user.points});` it is attached to `window.user` as its supposed to... On the other hand while trying to send `req.user.nick` its also not attached to `window`. What may be the problem?

Comment: What template engine are you using? Jade?

Comment: @PherricOxide Yes, Jade

Comment: As far as I know Mike's answer is correct; I don't think variables get attached to the window object like that, but rather they're just passed into your templates as strings. But you said req.user.points was actually attached to window.user? That intrigues me...

Comment: attached was a bad expression for this. What I meant was that `window.user` could get retrieved. As for now question solved. I need to stringify the object and than parse it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

render does not preserve objects. The object you pass the `.render` function gets used as string-macros for your template, so if your index template has a `{{ user }}` or `<% user %>` in it (syntax depending on the templating engine you picked), then it'll write the *string* that your `user` content coerces to into your file.

index:

```
<p>{{ user }}</p>
```

call:

```
res.render('index', {user: {"name": "monkey"}});
```

result:

```
<p>{"name": "monkey"}</p>
```

And that's text, not a JavaScript object. Of course we could make sure the string goes into a script block:

index:

```
<script> var user = {{ user }}; </script>
```

call:

```
res.render('index', {user: {"name": "monkey"}});
```

result:

```
<script> var user = {"name": "monkey"}; </script>
```

And now we can suddenly use it in the rest of our on-page JavaScript.